# Configure NppExec in Notepad++ for C programming

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, notepad++, nppexec

I am trying to configure NppExec so that I can run C codes directly from Notepad++. I followed this link http://windowsbro.blogspot.in/2012/10/compile-with-notepad-any-language.html to configure NppExec but it resulted in following error

```
NPP_SAVE: D:\Code\hello24.c
gcc "D:\Code\hello24.c"
Process started >>>
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file a.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
cmd /c "D:\Code\a.exe"
Process started >>>
'D:\Code\a.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
```

I also tried change the second line(**gcc "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"**) in Execute window by **C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe**, but then it resulted in following error:

```
NPP_SAVE: D:\Code\hello24.c
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
Process started >>>
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
cmd /c "D:\Code\a.exe"
Process started >>>
'D:\Code\a.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
```

any suggestions? I am new to this and if I have missed any detail kindly let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cannot open output file a.exe: Permission denied

This does not look like a problem with notepad++, more like a problem with your installation. Try to execute the command:

```
gcc "D:\Code\hello24.c"
```

from a commandline to debug the permission problem. Can you write to d:\Code\?